# How to center an element in parent div with floating element to the right

Tags: html, css

In the attached image I am trying to centery "harry" but it seems that doing `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't ignore the "remove" element on the right. Does anyone know how I can center "harry" while still having the "remove" button on the right?

[image]

Here is my existing html

```
<table class="week_table" summary="Users for week">
  <thead >
  <tr align="center" class="TableHeader">
    <th align="center" class="week_table_heading">
        <%= event.date.day.to_s + " " + event.date.strftime("%B") %>
    </th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<!--  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= event.remaining_spaces? %>
    </td>
</tr>-->

<% event.users.each do |user| %>
  <tr >
      <td class="week_table_row">
       <% if user == current_user %>
        <a class="RemoveButton"href=<%="welcome/remove_from_month?event_id="+event.id.to_s%>>remove </a>
      <%end%>
      <span class="UserName">
      <%= user.first_name %>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  <tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
<% if !event.users.include?(current_user) %>
      <a href=<%="welcome/sign_up_month?event_id="+event.id.to_s%>>Sign Up</a>

<% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `position:absolute` for the "remove" and `position:relative` for its container.

Comment: If I do that then the remove button no longer appears inside the white box but instead at the right edge of the screen.

Comment: posted my existing html.

Comment: That should work. I see no reason why it should go wrong. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/4n7j3egx/1//). There are some errors, such as the missing space before the first href, and the missing quotes around the value of he second href, but I don't think that influences things.

Comment: Can you create a snippet here in the question that demonstrates the problem? With the resulting HTML as seen in the browser, rather than the source you posted here. And the used CSS of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mr. Lister is right...

You have to:

```
.remove {position: absolute; right:0;}
.container-harry {position:relative}
```

and harry will be centred.

Comment: `.week_table { width:100%} /* or whatever...*/
.week_table_row { position:relative}
.RemoveButton { position:absolute; right:0}`

Comment: Here have you link on the [jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/samuells/yo0ya9gv/)

Comment: @Samuell Does that do what you wanted?